# Selenium: How to use captureentirepagescreenshot with remotedriver C#

Tags: selenium

In the Selenium docs I can see how to take a normal screenshot:

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html

But I would like to use captureentirepagescreenshot with a remote webdriver, C#

Is this possible? any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Please use selenium webdriver version 2.33. Below code is a c# code so please download selenium webdriver dlls for .net from link http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Selenium webdriver has inbuilt function called ITakesScreenshot to take screenshot runtime.

Please see below code

```
 `public static void SaveScreenShot(string screenshotFirstName)
    {
        var folderLocation = "Screenshot folder path";
        var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)Driver).GetScreenshot();
        var filename = new StringBuilder(folderLocation);
        filename.Append(screenshotFirstName);
        filename.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH_mm_ss"));\\append date and time
        filename.Append(".png"); \\append image extension
        screenshot.SaveAsFile(filename.ToString(), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

    }`
```

Hope this will work for you.

Thanks,
Anshul

Answer (score 0):

If you use a IWebDriver implementation (such as InternetExplorerDriver, FirefoxDriver) you can simply cast it to a ITakesScreenshot interface and use the GetScreenShot() method:

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
Screenshot screenShot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
screenShot.SaveAsFile(/*fullFileNameAndPath*/, ImageFormat.Png);
```

But if you want to to do this with a RemoteWebDriver you can't, because it doesn't implement the ITakesScreenshot interface. So, you have to create a new class based on RemoteWebDriver that implements this interface and adds the GetScreenshot() method such as:

```
public class ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver : RemoteWebDriver, ITakesScreenshot
{
    public ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver(Uri RemoteAdress, ICapabilities capabilities)
        : base(RemoteAdress, capabilities) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a <see cref="Screenshot"/> object representing the image of the page on the screen.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="Screenshot"/> object containing the image.</returns>
    public Screenshot GetScreenshot()
    {
        // Get the screenshot as base64.
        Response screenshotResponse = this.Execute(DriverCommand.Screenshot, null);
        string base64 = screenshotResponse.Value.ToString();

        // ... and convert it.
        return new Screenshot(base64);
    }       
}
```

Now you can use it as you would for a IWebDriver:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver(/*uri*/, /*capabilities*/);
Screenshot screenShot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
screenShot.SaveAsFile(/*fullFileNameAndPath*/, ImageFormat.Png);
```

It took me sometime to understand the maze of classes and interfaces for the drivers as well, but after a while it all makes sense.